# How to fix javac package does not exist?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am creating in my code a Java file, which I need to convert to a class. My file contains the following:

```java
import com.company.tpch.TpchApplication;
import com.company.tpch.TpchApplicationBuilder;
import com.speedment.runtime.core.ApplicationBuilder;
public class java {
    public void x() {
        TpchApplication app = new TpchApplicationBuilder()
                .withPassword("root")
                .withLogging(ApplicationBuilder.LogType.STREAM)
                .withLogging(ApplicationBuilder.LogType.APPLICATION_BUILDER)
                .withSkipCheckDatabaseConnectivity()
                .build();

    }
}
```

When I try to compile the file with

```
javac -d . C:\Users\s\Desktop\demo\src\main\java\java.java
```

I have these errors:

```
import com.company.tpch.TpchApplication;
                       ^
C:\Users\s\Desktop\demo\src\main\java\java.java:2: error: package com.company.tpch does not exist
import com.company.tpch.TpchApplicationBuilder;
                       ^
C:\Users\s\Desktop\demo\src\main\java\java.java:3: error: package com.speedment.runtime.core does not exist
import com.speedment.runtime.core.ApplicationBuilder;
                                 ^
C:\Users\s\Desktop\demo\src\main\java\java.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        TpchApplication app = new TpchApplicationBuilder()
        ^
  symbol:   class TpchApplication
  location: class java
C:\Users\s\Desktop\demo\src\main\java\java.java:11: error: package ApplicationBuilder does not exist
                .withLogging(ApplicationBuilder.LogType.APPLICATION_BUILDER)
                                               ^
C:\Users\s\Desktop\demo\src\main\java\java.java:10: error: package ApplicationBuilder does not exist
                .withLogging(ApplicationBuilder.LogType.STREAM)
                                               ^

  symbol:   class TpchApplicationBuilder
  location: class java
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You should be *in* the directory `C:\Users\s\Desktop\demo\src\main\java`, and the command should be `javac -d . java.java`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add all classes that are used to your command. Like this:

```
javac com/company/tpch/TpchApplication com/company/tpch/TpchApplicationBuilder java.java
```

Of course you have to change this according to your directory structure, since I don't know it.

Anyway I would recommend an IDE that compiles your whole project at once like IntelliJ/Eclipse and/or a dependency tool like Maven/Gradle.

Comment: @programmer You're kidding, right? You can't name directories to the `javac` command like this. Did you actually try it?